# Member variables changing on their own when multithreading c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, c++11, stdthread

This is my first attempt at multithreading my code.

The code consists of a class Simulation that creates individual Simulation objects. Since I need to run several of them I wanted to run them in parallel across multiple threads. The code works perfectly fine in serial but when assigning each simulation object method to a different thread I encounter segmentation faults at different times (usually very early on) which I assume is due to some kind of data racing happening. Digging a bit deeper I found that some member variables seem to get reinitialised or just change values (not consistently in every run). It is clear to me that some resources are getting mixed up but how can that happen when I am running each simulation in an independent thread (or so I think)?

Heres a simplified version of the code.

Simulation class:

```
   class Simulation{
    public:
    void run(){
        //Complicated stuff;                    
       }
    };
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(){
        vector<Simulation> simulations;
        vector<thread> threads;

    for (int i=0; i<nSimulations; i++){
        simulations.push_back(
            Simulation(params));
        threads.push_back(thread(&Simulation::run,
            std::ref(simulations[i])));
    }

    for (int i=0; i<nSimulations; i++){
        threads[i].join();
        simulations[i].saveToFile("test.dat");
    }

return 0;
}
```

Is there anything inherently wrong with this piece of code? The actual code is quite complicated so at least I would like to know if this is the right way to multithread different object methods to different threads.

Comment: You cannot pass `std::ref(simulations[i])` as parameter to thread because simulations is `vector`, and while calling `push_back` method its elements are reallocated, so you will have invalid pointer in thread object to Simulation object.

Comment: You can easily prevent reallocation by reserving vector space: `simulations.reserve(nSimulations);`. By the way, using `simulations.back()` more clearly expresses your intent than `simulations[i]`. Also, consider using `emplace_back` with both vectors.

Comment: Your `Simulation` objects don't have any mutable members - only `run()`.  Is `run()` somehow changing, or is your example incomplete and not reproducible?  I recommend you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Didn't know `push_back` reallocates the vector. @DanielLangr Using simulations.reserve(nSimulations) solves the problem. Is there, perhaps, a more elegant way of achieving the same result overall?

Comment: If your `Simulation` objects are copyable, you can just `std::vector<Simulation> simulations(n, { params });` which initialises them all as copies in the constructor of the vector.

Comment: @CarlesRàfols It depens on what you mean by _elegant_. With C++17 enabled parallelism, I would just use `std::for_each` with parallel execution policy. You can also look at `std::async`, it's hard to say whether or not you need `std::thread`s.

Comment: @DanielLangr The threads still have references to distinct `Simulation` objects, which are located in `simulations`

Comment: @Caleth Sorry, I misinterpreted your comment. However, I would expect that `param` are changing across iterations (which is not shown in the code for the sake of simplicity). But maybe they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest change that fixes your issue is to construct all the simulations before you start any threads.

```
int main(){
    vector<Simulation> simulations;
    for (int i=0; i<nSimulations; i++){
        simulations.push_back(Simulation(params)); // or emplace_back(params)
    }
    // or vector<Simulation> simulations(nSimulations, Simulation(params));

    vector<thread> threads;   
    for (int i=0; i<nSimulations; i++){
        threads.push_back(thread(&Simulation::run, std::ref(simulations[i])));
    }

    for (int i=0; i<nSimulations; i++){
        threads[i].join();
        simulations[i].saveToFile("test.dat");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want a minimal fix, call `.capacity()` once.

Comment: @Deduplicator do you mean `reserve(nSimulations)`?

Answer (score 2):

You should be *very cautious* when dealing with the address of `std::vector` elements, they will change when you `push_back` more elements.

```
    vector<Simulation> simulations;

for (int i=0; i<nSimulations; i++){
    simulations.push_back(
        Simulation(params));
    threads.push_back(thread(&Simulation::run,
        std::ref(simulations[i])));  // <-- This place !
}
```

Here you save the addresses of vector element in a `for` loop, the previous addresses will be invalidated during vector enlargement.

Comment: what to do instead would be nice

Comment: How could I achieve the intended behaviour in this case?

Comment: `.push_back()` only re-allocates if there is insufficient capacity. A simple call to `.reserve()` before the loop would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers solve the simple case requested, where we know in advance the number of simulations. The solution is to simply reserve enough space in the Simulation vector to that reallocation never occurs.

But what if the number of Simulations was not known, or simulations must be added ad-hoc?

One answer might be to store simulations in a `std::list` rather than a `std::vector`. However, we then lose the ability to access simulations randomly.

We might solve this by implementing a Simulation in terms of a handle/body idiom. The handle is moveable, and controls the lifetime of the actual implementation.

Am example (in which I have also given the concept of a running simulation its own class):

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

struct SimulationParams {};

struct Simulation
{
    // noncopyable
    Simulation(Simulation const&) = delete;
    Simulation& operator=(Simulation const&) = delete;

    Simulation(SimulationParams params);

    void run()
    {
        // complicated stuff
    }

    void saveToFile(std::string const& path);
};

class SimulationHandle
{
    using impl_class = Simulation;
    using impl_type = std::unique_ptr<impl_class>;
    impl_type impl_;

public:

    SimulationHandle(SimulationParams params)
    : impl_(std::make_unique<impl_class>(std::move(params)))
    {}

    auto saveToFile(std::string const& path) -> decltype(auto)
    {
        return implementation().saveToFile(path);        
    }

    auto runInThread() -> std::thread
    {
        return std::thread { 
            [&sim = this->implementation()]
            {
                sim.run();
            }
        };
    }

    auto implementation() -> impl_class& 
    {
        return *impl_;
    }
};

struct RunningSimulation
{
    RunningSimulation(SimulationParams params)
    : simHandle_{ std::move(params) }
    , thread_ { simHandle_.runInThread() }
    {

    }

    void join()
    {
        if (thread_.joinable())
            thread_.join();
    }

    void saveToFile(std::string const& path)
    {
        join();
        simHandle_.saveToFile(path);
    }

private:
    // DEPENDENCY: ORDER
    //     During constructor, thread_ depends on simHandle_ being constructed
    SimulationHandle simHandle_;
    std::thread thread_;
};

extern int nSimulations;

int main(){
    using std::vector;

    vector<RunningSimulation> simulations;

    for (int i=0; i<nSimulations; i++)
        simulations.emplace_back(SimulationParams());

    for(auto&& rs : simulations)
        rs.saveToFile("test.dat");

    return 0;
}
```

Further enhancements:

The current handle is implemented in terms of `unique_ptr` - which means only one handle can own a simulation. We might wish to index the simulation in a number of ways, which would require more than one handle.

One possible solution to this would be to simply replace the `unique_ptr` with `shared_ptr`, for shared ownership. Another might be to have the concept of a lifetime control handle (implemented with `shared_ptr`) and lifetime monitors (implemented with `weak_ptr`).